# Wordpress custom WP_query for retrieving pages by menu_order giving random posts

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My `category.php` page has a description of the category and related pages ('products').

I'm using a `WP_query` to get the pages which work, only the posts are randomly displayed instead of ordered by menu_order.

```
  $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'exclude' => '',
  'cat' => $category->term_id,
  'parent' => -1,
  'offset' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to limit the `posts_per_page` but that still gives a random pages effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and see if it works:

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby' => array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC' )
);
```

Comment: And the randomness stopped. Thanks a lot @Ruvee! Why does this solves the issue?